# i need to remove bootstrap navigation bar horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootply link to my code:http://www.bootply.com/vy8NId1isb.
 The navigation bar will display an horizontal scrollbar when in tablet/phone screen size, when the expand icon is clicked.How do I remove it ? Overflow-x: hidden is not helping.

Comment: If you want to remove the responsive style of bootstrap. Why don't you just create a style without using a class from bootstrap. You can't since they create the media queries for it. It is also difficult to set it to default one by one.

Comment: try this css: `.navbar-collapse{overflow-x: hidden}

Comment: Mukesh,u da real mvp

Answer (score 0):

use below css and try

```
.navbar-form{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add this to your css code

```
overflow-x: hidden !important;
```